# How do I find a number preceded by a marker, then make that number a variable?

Tags: php, html, regex

I want to find all numbers preceded by `class="g-b">$`, then make that number a variable.

Given HTML code like this:

```
class="g-b">$195.00</div><span class="ship fee">+$10.00 shipping
```

Right now I think I should use regex to find terms with `class="g-b">$` in them, but I end up fetching the preceding text as well when I only want the number. Is there a way to only fetch the number? Should I just do another regex to get the number?

Comment: Isn't that number preceded by `$` as well?

Comment: Maybe start here to learn regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Do you want all the numbers? Or just one or ? What exactly is your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my interactive php shell (started with php -a):

```
php > $a = 'class="g-b">$195.00</div><span class="ship fee">+$10.00 shipping'
php > preg_match('/class="g-b">\$([\d\.]+)/g', $a, $matches);
php > var_dump($matches);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "class="g-b">$195.00"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "195.00"
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
regexp = /class=\"g-b\">\$(\d+\.?\d{0,2})\+\$(\d+\.\d{0,2}) /;
x = regexp.exec( text );
```

That will save the numbers as array "x";

Answer (score 0):

You wanna use look ahead to only get the digits:

like the following...
'If you want to get whole numbers

```
(?<="g-b">$)\d+
```

'Or if you want whole numbers and the decimal places:

```
 (?<="g-b">$)\d+[.]\d+
```